# Sending and Recieving data from web server in JQM app using Slim framework

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, rest, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM Mobile app that interacts with a REST Api using Slim Framework, Testing it on localhost everything works well, however when i uploaded the API to my web server only pages that use the GET connect to the server, all POST requests fail to connect to the server. Code below

Index.html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Mobile APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/itfjobportal.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/custom.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
    {
     $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
     $.support.cors = true;
     });    
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1> Login Page</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="login-container">
        <form action="" method="post" name="admin" id="admin">
                <div id="failedLogin"></div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="">
            <div id="lower">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Login" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="lock">
            </div>
        </form>

            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="js/ajaxGetPost.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",'#submitbutton',function() {

        var username=$('#username').val();
        var password=$('#password').val();

        if (username=='') {
            alert("Please enter username");
            $('#username').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (password=='') {
            alert("Please enter password");
            $('#password').focus();
            return false;
        }

        encode=JSON.stringify({'username': username, 'password': password});

        var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/api/doLogin';

            post_data(url,encode, function(data)
            {
                if(data.status == 'failed') {
                     $("#failedLogin").html('Supplied credentials are invalid');
                } else {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));

                    location.href = 'index.php';
                }

            });

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
</code>
```

My ajaxGetPost.js

```
function post_data(url,encodedata, success)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
       crossDomain: true,
        data :encodedata,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        restful:true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache:false,
        timeout:20000,
        async:true,
        beforeSend :function(data) { $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"b", text:"LOADING... Please Wait...", textonly:true, textVisible: true}); },

       complete: function() {$.mobile.loading('hide');},                    
        success:function(data){
           //   alert(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
          //    alert(JSON.stringify(data));     
       alert("Error Sending Data");
        }
    });
}

function get_data(type,url, success)
{
$.ajax({
type:type,
url:url,
dataType:"json",
restful:true,
cache:false,
timeout:20000,
async:true,
beforeSend :function(data) { $.mobile.loading('show') },
complete: function() {$.mobile.loading('hide') },                   
success:function(data){
success.call(this, data);
},
error:function(data){
alert("Error Retrieving Data");
}
});
}
```

Below is the index.php on the server

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require 'dbConfig.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
//include('../lib/config.php');

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$slim_app = new \Slim\Slim();

$slim_app->post('/doLogin','doLogin');
$slim_app->get('/loadJobs','loadJobs');
$slim_app->post('/applyJob','applyJob');
$slim_app->post('/newUser','newUser');
$slim_app->post('/editUser','editUser');
$slim_app->get('/loadEditUser/:eid','loadEditUser');
$slim_app->get('/deleteUser/:did','deleteUser');


$slim_app->run();

function doLogin() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $update = json_decode($request->getBody()); 

    try {
        $db = getDB();      
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM job_seeker where username=:username1 AND pwd=:password1 AND status=1");
        $stmt->bindValue(':username1', $update->username, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password1', $update->password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
        $db = null;
        if(count($rows)) {          
            echo '{"status": "success"}';
        }
        else {
            echo '{"status": "failed"}';}
    } catch(PDOException $e) {      
        echo '{"error":{"msg":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

}
```

I also have a .htaccess file as so, As you can see I already have the  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in the htaccess but i still put it up in the index.php file incase it is not redirecting properly

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

# RewriteBase /

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, So after all the trouble, it happens to be that there was no error with the code. I tested the API Using Advanced Rest Client for Chrome and it worked well. So I found out that the problem was with my config.xml file since i was using phonegap build, the persmissions in the platform specific manifest xml file e.g. andriodmanifest.xml where not applying so i had to add the following code to the config.xml file to enable the app connect to internet.

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```